# Quando devo ou não usar o if sem chaves?

Tags: javascript, c#

Eu costumo usar sempre com chaves pois até hoje não sei como é exatamente o funcionamento do if sem chaves e se o else também pode ser sem chaves. Existe alguma variação de comportamento entre javascript e C#? E entre outras linguagens?

Alguns exemplos que me deixariam confuso se funcionam ou não:

Exemplo 1:

```
if(true)
    variavel = 55;
else
    variavel = 100;
```

Exemplo 2:

```
if(true)
    variavel1 = 55;
    variavel2 = 40;
else
    variavel1 = 100;
    variavel2 = 150;
```

Exemplo 3

```
if (true)
   variavel1 = 55;
else{
   variavel1 = 100;
   variavel2 = 200;
}
```

Comment: Simplesmente quando a instrução que você precise valida seja feita em uma unica linha, após a primeira linha o que vinhe não estará dentro do seu if ou else. o ideal mesmo é sempre usar.

Comment: Todos esses exemplos funcionam(compilam), podem é não fazer o que você pretende. Por isso use sempre chaves.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O `IF` sem chaves faz com que apenas a próxima expressão seja avaliada.

Em uma variação do seu exemplo 2,

```
if(variavel == true)
    variavel1 = 55;  //Será executado apenas se variavel == true;
    variavel2 = 40;  // Será executado incondicionalmente.
```

Aliás, uma maneira melhor de visualizar o código acima seria:

```
if(variavel == true)
    variavel1 = 55;

variavel2 = 40;
```

Perceba que *expressão* é diferente de *linha*. A sequência abaixo se comportará *exatamente* da mesma maneira da variação do exemplo 2:

```
if(variavel == true)
    variavel1 = 55; variavel2 = 40;
//                     ^- Execução incondicional
//     ^- Execução condicional
```

Comment: A explicação da expressão != linha foi essencial pro meu entendimento! Só continuo com a dúvida em relação ao else nesses mesmos casos.